# ConcurrentModificationException thrown without directly looping through collection

Tags: java, iterator

I have the following code:

```
// Creates ArrayList with integers 0-9
ArrayList<Integer> intKeys = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    intKeys.add(x);
}

// Creates iterator with integers 0-9
Iterator<Integer> allKeys = intKeys.iterator();

// Loops 10 times, each time obtaining a key to remove from the ArrayList
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    Integer key = allKeys.next();
    intKeys.remove(key);
}
```

I understand that ConcurrentModificationException is thrown if an element of a collection is removed while the collection is being looped over, such as:

```
for (String key : someCollection) {
    someCollection.remove(key);    
}
```

but right now I'm looping over nothing - just an arbitrary number of times. Furthermore, the error line is interestingly `Integer key = allKeys.next();` What could be the cause of this exception?

Comment: "but right now I'm looping over nothing" you are looping over `intKeys` list by `allKeys.next();` but you are also modifying that list in next step via `intKeys.remove(key);`. Don't you think that this can affect `Iterator<Integer> allKeys` (which assumes that array will not be modified by anyone else while it is looping over it)?

Comment: "as I am not looping through a collection" what do you think `allKeys.next();` does? `allKeys` is an Iterator. If you want to remove element which it returned, then use `allKeys.remove()` not `intKeys.remove(key);` (where `intKeys` is List).

Comment: @Pshemo Oh, I see. Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the list's `Iterator` object at all when you are removing items while looping.

If you are removing all the items from the list:

```
while (!list.isEmpty()) {
    Integer i = list.remove(0);
    //Do something with the item
}
```

Otherwise, you can iterate *without* the iterator:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
    //Do something with the list
}
```